# Keep Scanning in Input using Recursion with Go

Tags: go, recursion, input

I am trying to do a problem without using for/while loops and with recursion. The problem gives you an input in this format:

[image: 2 4 3 -1 1 14 5 9 6 -53 32 16]

where "2" is the number of queries and each query contains the length of a list of digits followed by the digits. I need to scan in all the information and print out the sum of the digits(in this case 3 + -1 + 1 + 14 and 9 + 6 + -53 + 32 + 16). I am trying to use recursion to scan in the digits, but I can't seem to scan them in properly. Does any

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    recur(n)
}

func print_sum(l int, sum int) int {
    if l == 0 {
        return sum
    }
    var next_digit int
    fmt.Scan(next_digit)
    print_sum(l-1, sum+next_digit)
    return 0
}
func recur(queries int) {
    if queries == 0 {
        return
    }
    var next_len int
    fmt.Scan(next_len)
    print_sum(next_len, 0)
    recur(queries - 1)
}
```

Comment: what does `find_sum` do?

Comment: oh sorry, it is supposed to be print_sum not find_sum. the function should be recursive.

Comment: You discard return values, for example, Scan and print_sum, and so on. Here is an answer to your original question: https://play.golang.org/p/6mWGLRe2TXi Compare this answer to your code.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I will try to read and understand it. so to make my current code work, can I pass in an array from the main function to store the calculated values?

Comment: @AllenYe:  In this revised version, the called run function returns an array of calculated values to the main function, where the values are printed: https://play.golang.org/p/lmql0TLv9Vu . The readN function creates the sums calculated values array and passes it down to the readX function.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution, here is the code if anyone wants to look at it: https://github.com/allenye66/Recursive-Sum-of-Squares